# The 1st, 2nd, and 10th terms of an arithmetic series are equal to 1st, 4th, 17th terms of a geometric series respectively.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

For the arithmetic series, the 1st number is a, the common difference is d.
For the geometric series, the common ratio is r.
How to figure out the value of r?

Comment: Use what you are told.  Write expression for the terms of the series in terms of the first term, the ratio of the geometric series, and the difference of the arithmetic series.  Set the corresponding terms equal and solve the simultaneous equations.

Comment: @RossMillikan See my comments following the answer of Prasiortle.  While I suspect that your comment represents the only viable approach, I don't think it is fair to expect an algebra-precalculus student to be able to handle it.

Comment: @user2661923 In my deleted comment, $A$ and $a$ are not the same thing and I never said $A$ was the first term.  I said 1) $a_k = A + kd$ and $a_1 = A+d = a$.  So $A = a-d$.

Comment: @user2661923:  an algebra-precalculus student should be able to write down the equations.  It then depends on the tools available.  A graphing calculator should allow an approximate value to be found, but I agree there is probably a typo.

Comment: @fleablood In hindsight, you're right.  I read your original comment too hastily.

Answer (score 1):

The $1$st, $2$nd, and $10$th terms of the arithmetic series are $a$, $a+d$, and $a+9d$; similarly, the $1$st, $4$th, and $17$th terms of the geometric series are $a$, $ar^3$, and $ar^{16}$. Thus we have $a+d = ar^3$ and $a+9d = ar^{16}$, so subtracting these equations gives $8d = a\left(r^{16}-r^3\right)$. Substituting this into the first equation now yields $$\begin{align*}&a+\frac{a}{8}\left(r^{16}-r^3\right) = ar^3 \\ &\iff 1+\frac{1}{8}\left(r^{16}-r^3\right) = r^3 \quad \text{(assuming we don't have } a = d = r = 0 \text{)} \\ &\iff r^{16}-9r^3+8 = 0 \\ &\iff (r-1)\left(r^{15}+r^{14}+\dotsb+r^3-8r^2-8r-8\right) = 0,\end{align*}$$ and so either $r = 1$ (giving $d = 0$), or (numerically) $r \approx 1.07499$.

Comment: How did you calculated the value of r? I had also got the equation,r^16-9r^3+8=0. But could not figure out using usual scientific calculator.

Comment: I suspect that your answer is the *best* that one can do.  However, assuming so, this makes the problem unfair, and (perhaps) makes your answer *unfair*.  That is, given the problem's tags, in the algebra-precalculus world, the student isn't taught how to grapple with $~r^{16} - 9r^3 + 8 = 0.$

Comment: @swarna I suspect that some computer algebra system was used.

Comment: It is a problem from secondary school math textbook. I now doubt if the problem is given correctly.

Comment: @swarna Quite plausibly, because $~(17-1)~$ is not a multiple of $~(4-1).~$  Perhaps the intent was to involve the $~7$-th term in the geometric series, rather than the $~17$-th term.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I used Mathematica to solve this equation numerically, of course. If you were to change it to the $7$th term, the equation would give $r \in \left\{1,2\right\}$, so that indeed might have been the intention!